# I am able to to use adb from my PC to grant permission to my app but not in a shell executed in my own app code

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, adb

I am able to grant permissions to my app from my PC with adb like this:

```
 adb shell pm grant com.companyname.appname android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

It works great, without needing to move my app as system app or gain root access.
But when I try to run a shell in my own app it doesn't work:

```
pm grant com.companyname.appname android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

Why is that?

Comment: `adb shell` executes commands from a privileged process. Your app's process lacks those rights.

Comment: Can I run adb shell directly on my phone?

Comment: No. On a rooted phone, my understanding is that you can run shell commands from a privileged process, though I have not tried this myself. More generally... if any app could give themselves any permission that they wanted, without user input, what would be the point of having the permissions in the first place?